# Is there a way to access a live command shell for Ubuntu server online?

Tags: installation, command-line, gnome, server, bash

I have setup a LAMP server with ubuntu server that I plan to do some game hosting with. Right now I am using Webmin for remoting in to my server. One major problem with webmin however, is that you can only enter one command into the command shell and are unable to use editors such as nano or vim through it. I would really like a live, responsive, command shell so I can work on my server where ever I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a SSH server (package `openssh-server`) on your server and a SSH client (package `openssh-client` on Ubuntu, there's a client for about any other system, too) on the hosts you want to access your server from.

Then you can use something like

```
  ssh server.example.com
```

on your local host to get a full remote shell on your server.